# ¿Cómo se puede cambiar el color de un texto creado dentro de un canvas en Tkinter/Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Intento hacer una ventana que contiene un canvas donde se puedan cargar imágenes y escribir texto sobre ellas, pero que luego se pueda cambiar interactivamente el color del texto eligiéndolo tal vez de ColorChooser. Pero una vez que se crea el texto no hay manera de cambiarle el color. He intentado con labels y el método canvas create pero no funciona. ¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo se puede hacer?

(Actualización)
Sí, perdón, estaba un poco apurado cuando escribí la pregunta: Lo de MarkDown no entendí bien, no sé si funcione...

```
entrada1 = StringVar()

etxt1=Entry (root, width=70, textvariable=entrada1)
etxt1.grid(row=1, columnspan=4, padx=2, pady=2)

btxt1=Button (f2, text="AGREGAR", width=8, height=1, bg="white", fg="black", relief=GROOVE, overrelief=RAISED, command=lambda:canvas.create_text(cw/2, 30, anchor=CENTER, text=etxt1.get(), activefill="yellow" fill=txtcolor, justify=CENTER, tags=CURRENT))
btxt1.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=1, pady=1)
```

Este es parte del código que me inserta el texto en el canvas. No uso una función definida para ello sino directamente en la acción del botón y así me funciona, inserta dentro del canvas el texto que yo haya escrito en el Entry cuando hago clic en el botón "btxt1", se resalta en color amarillo cuando le paso el puntero del mouse por encima y puedo moverlo con canvas.move y bind a las teclas de flecha del teclado porque no sé cómo moverlo haciendo clic y arrastrando con el mouse (aunque ya lo he intentado no funciona sino sólo con objetos dibujados como oval, line, etc.). El color del texto al inicio se lo paso con una variable "txtcolor" que al inicio está especificado como "white". Espero entiendan algo. Saludos

ACTUALIZACIÓN:
Ok, muchas gracias. Sí funcionó tu ejemplo. Ahora el código está así y funcionando:

```
# Función para crear el texto que previamente lo introduje en un Entry:

def texto1():
    global texto1
    try:
        texto1 = canvas.create_text(cw/2, 30, text=etxt1.get(), anchor=CENTER, font=ft, fill="white")
    except:
        pass

# Función para cambiar el color de ese texto:
def cambio_color1():
    color = askcolor()
    canvas.itemconfigure(texto1, fill= color[1])
```

Espero que a alguien más pueda servirle este ejemplo. Saludos y gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola toño podrías explicarnos que has intentado en código por favor

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Toño. Te he respondido con dos ejemplos (uno usando `create_text()` y otro `Label` para almacenar el texto), miratelo a ver si te sirve. Te recomiendo que cuando preguntes, con el fin de dar una respuesta lo más acertada posible, pongas un ejemplo funcional de tú código, puedes mirarte [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Si incluyes código usa [MarkDown](http://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) para formatearlo correctamente (selecciona el código y pulsa `Ctrl + k`). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

❶ Si usas el método `create_text()` que proporciona `Canvas` para introducir texto dentro de tu canvas puedes cambiar fácilmente el color  usando el método `itemconfigure()`. Te dejo un ejemplo minimalista de como podria ser:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor


def cambiar_color():
    color = askcolor()
    canvas.itemconfigure(texto,fill= color[1])

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
texto = canvas.create_text(420,200,text='¡Hola Mundo!', anchor='e', font=("Courier", 25))
botonC = tk.Button(text='Selecciona color', command=cambiar_color).pack()
root.geometry('600x400')
root.mainloop()
```

En el ejemplo se usa un botón que llama a la función `cambiar_color()` donde se invoca a un `colorchooser` para que se seleccione un color y después cambia el color del texto usando `itemconfigure()`

Mediante `itemconfigure()` puedes cambiar los demás parámetros del texto como la fuente, el tamaño o el mismo texto mostrado.

❷ Si usas un `Label` para agregar el texto puedes hacer los mismo usando el método `configure()`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor


def cambiar_color():
    color = askcolor()
    texto.configure(fg=color[1])  

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

texto = tk.Label(canvas, text='¡Hola Mundo!', fg='black', font=("Helvetica", 20))
texto.pack()
canvas.create_window(300, 200, window=texto)

botonC = tk.Button(text='Selecciona color', command=cambiar_color).pack()
root.geometry('600x400')
root.mainloop()
```

**Aviso:** ambos códigos son válido para `Python 3.x` pero si usas `Python 2.x`  simplemente modifica adecuadamente los `import` cambiandolos por:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkColorChooser import askcolor
```

Sin tener tu código y cómo implementas la agregación del texto a tu lienzo es difícil orientarte mejor, pero creo que esto te puede servir como idea.